# Which architecture is suited the best for a changing URL?

Tags: url, architecture, client-server, soa, p2p

Exam Question: You're using an external API, where the URL changes frequently. Which architecture is suited the best to solve this problem, without ever-changing the code for the program again?

I recently took an exam and there was this task to which i still cannot figure out the appropriate answer.The architectures mentioned in the lecture were P2P, C/S and SOA.

If anyone has a clue... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is p2p. In a Peer-to-peer network, computers advertise their services capabilities on the network. A changing URL would not be a problem, as the new URL is published to the network automatically and picked up by the consumers of the API.

In SOA and Client/Server the consumers of the API have no means to know about a change in the API URL.